# appengine returns error

Tags: google-app-engine

I just did appengine's sample Guestbook following the guide, it's completely followed the guide. The app runs well on local. Then I deployed it to appengine via Eclipse successfully. I can see my app via the management portal. But I could access my app via http://.appspot.com, the browser shows error:

```
Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems    preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

After I see the error in browser, I check the admin log, see this:

```
2012-12-05 04:26:32.792 / 200 67ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
116.246.26.29 - - [05/Dec/2012:04:26:32 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 867 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4" "evanguestbook.appspot.com" ms=68 cpu_ms=64 cpm_usd=0.000097 instance=00c61b117c85ed8047fbc561bc883e1ac1c50c
```

Looks no error in log.

And from the admin log, I see this:

```
API serving not allowed for this application
```

Did I do sometime wrong? Or I missed something to do?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs of the Admin console?

Comment: I checked admin console, the log looks no error.

Comment: Are you trying to use the endpoints API?

Comment: No. I don't use endpoints API.

Comment: It's network problem. It seems it's hard to access appspot.com from outside of USA.

Comment: It seems to be working now, right? Accessed from EU:  evanguestbook.appspot.com

Comment: Accessed from Asia: evanguestbook.appspot.com ... it works. Most likely a network issue as noted earlier.

Comment: "API serving not allowed for this application" is a red herring, and shouldn't be relevant unless you are trying to use Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on a few things:

- Make sure that there is no network issue between your local machine and the outside network due to which you are not able to reach your application on .appspot.com domain. Any Proxy Servers in your network?
- This might seem trivial, but I want to confirm based on your question if you are indeed visiting a url for your application that looks like: http://APP_ID.appspot.com, where APP_ID is your application id.
- If above points look fine, I suggest what Thanos said. Login to the AppEngine console, visit the Logs section and see if you can find anything there.